# Upload XML/CSV File using Rest Api in java

Tags: java, xml, rest, csv, jersey

I just ask for help from the nearby comunity on StackOverflow upload XML or CSV file using the REST API in Java .

URL :

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8080
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/HSMV5/api/import
Request Method:POST
```

Request Playload :

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryTnLhEykB6lreFMtz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="aaaa.xml"; filename="aaaa.xml"
Content-Type: text/xml


------WebKitFormBoundaryTnLhEykB6lreFMtz--
```

here is my source code:

```
@Path("/")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA })
public class Dispatcher {
    @POST
    @Path("/import")
    public Response importpostFile(
            @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail)
            throws HsmRestServiceException {
        System.out.println(fileDetail.getFileName());
        return importFile.doPost(null);
    }

}
```

at compile variables returns null :

```
uploadedInputStream : null
fileDetail : null
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The name (`name="aaaa.xml"`) needs to the same as the value in the `@FormDataParam`. That's why it's null, because it's the wrong name. There *is* no part with the name `file`
2. I don't see any data. The data should appear between these lines.

   ```
   Content-Type: text/xml


   ------WebKitFormBoundaryTnLhEykB6lreFMtz--
   ```

   That's also something you will need to figure out.

Comment: thank you for your answer yesterday I understood that the problem come from the name property of the form.
here is the form to use in top

Answer (score 0):

here is the form to use :

```
     <tr class="pairRowTab">
            <td>
                <bean:message key="table.dateFormat"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <html:file property="dateFormatFile" size="70"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="impairRowTab">
            <td>
                <bean:message key="table.separateur"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <html:file property="separateurFile" size="70"/> 
            </td>
        </tr>
```